# Ubuntu boots to tty instead of desktop after upgrade to 18.10

Tags: 18.04, gui, 18.10

Today I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10 and something strange happened.

When I fire up the laptop it automatically enters the tty1 interface. Then I need to enter a command to go to graphical interface. This also happened once on 18.04 but then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> and everything was fine, but it doesn't seem to fix it now.

Any idea why is this happening? I tried some thing from the internet and still the same.

Drivers are same as the one I had on 18.04 and everything is updated but I guess that is not a problem since I can enter graphical interface with a command from tty1. I want it to go directly to graphical interface.

I already tried

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

but it's still the same after reboot

This command

```
sudo systemctl start gdm3.service
```

starts the graphical interface but only after I type it... it is going back to tty1 again after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution. I will just reinstall the system. And before you try to mark my post as a duplicate first read it bcs I said I already tried those things.

Comment: I also checked that too.. everything was fine so the problem is not there..

Comment: First it was "quiet splash" and it wasn't working.. then I changed it to empty string " " and still nothing

Comment: I already did that and none of them worked..I will reinstall system anyway.. I don't have anything important on it so its not a big deal

Comment: Yeah of course.